# Adobe Illustrator lags on Mac as Admin user but not Guest

Tags: macos, adobe-illustrator

I've been having a problem with Adobe Illustrator for a year plus where it constantly lags (rainbow spinning wheel on my Mac) and is almost unusable.  Fortunately I don't use it much so I've been able to put up with it.  The problem is very similar to the one documented here http://forums.adobe.com/message/3895439#3895439.

After much trial and error I've been able to isolate the problem/solution ... When I login to my Mac with a guest account it works fine.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is it really "admin account vs. guest account" or is it "lived-in account vs. clean account"? Try creating a new, clean admin account, and before you go customizing settings or installing anything, see if the lag happens or not.

If the lag doesn't happen on a new, clean admin account, then you can start looking at what's different in your "lived-in" admin account vs. a clean account.  Maybe you've installed Application Enhancer or SIMBL or other Input Manager hacks that are screwing up your performance.  Maybe you always leave an email client or web browser running in the background on your lived-in account, but you didn't do that on the new clean account.

If the lag still happens on a new, clean admin account, then you can test the "admin vs. non-admin" hypothesis by creating a new, clean non-admin account (really create an account, don't just use the guest account). Then see if you get the lag there.

I strongly suspect that the real difference is a lived-in account vs. a new, clean account. Although it might not come down to settings differences as much as how your behavior patterns are different on your lived-in account than a new clean account (like you're more likely to have more apps open in the background on your lived-in account).

Comment: Thats what I meant with the whole Admin-vs-Guest thing.  I'm sure its not actually the "Admin" part thats causing the issue, rather its conflicting with something I have on my "lived-in" account ... I was hoping someone knew of certain common programs that caused these problems.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a problem like this, check whether dictating is turned on. If it is, turn it off, it is likely going to solve the lag.